# Fail to start app when adding zipkin and sleuth

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-cloud-sleuth

I created a spring boot 2.1.2 basic web app using the initializr tool. The app starts fine and responds to a hello world kinda request. When I then attempted to add zipkin and sleuth, I now get an error.

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-zipkin</artifactId>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-sleuth</artifactId>
</dependency>

org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanDefinitionStoreException: Failed to process import candidates for configuration class [org.springframework.cloud.sleuth.instrument.web.TraceWebServletAutoConfiguration]; nested exception is java.io.FileNotFoundException: class path resource [org/springframework/web/servlet/handler/HandlerInterceptorAdapter.class] cannot be opened because it does not exist
at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser.processImports(ConfigurationClassParser.java:599) ~[spring-context-5.1.4.RELEASE.jar:5.1.4.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser.doProcessConfigurationClass(ConfigurationClassParser.java:302) ~[spring-context-5.1.4.RELEASE.jar:5.1.4.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser.processConfigurationClass(ConfigurationClassParser.java:242) ~[spring-context-5.1.4.RELEASE.jar:5.1.4.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser.processImports(ConfigurationClassParser.java:589) ~[spring-context-5.1.4.RELEASE.jar:5.1.4.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser.access$900(ConfigurationClassParser.java:108) ~[spring-context-5.1.4.RELEASE.jar:5.1.4.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser$DeferredImportSelectorGroupingHandler.lambda$processGroupImports$1(ConfigurationClassParser.java:808) ~[spring-context-5.1.4.RELEASE.jar:5.1.4.RELEASE]
at java.util.ArrayList.forEach(ArrayList.java:1257) ~[na:1.8.0_152]
at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser$DeferredImportSelectorGroupingHandler.processGroupImports(ConfigurationClassParser.java:804) ~[spring-context-5.1.4.RELEASE.jar:5.1.4.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser$DeferredImportSelectorHandler.process(ConfigurationClassParser.java:774) ~[spring-context-5.1.4.RELEASE.jar:5.1.4.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser.parse(ConfigurationClassParser.java:185) ~[spring-context-5.1.4.RELEASE.jar:5.1.4.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.processConfigBeanDefinitions(ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.java:315) ~[spring-context-5.1.4.RELEASE.jar:5.1.4.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.postProcessBeanDefinitionRegistry(ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.java:232) ~[spring-context-5.1.4.RELEASE.jar:5.1.4.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.context.support.PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.invokeBeanDefinitionRegistryPostProcessors(PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.java:275) ~[spring-context-5.1.4.RELEASE.jar:5.1.4.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.context.support.PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.invokeBeanFactoryPostProcessors(PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.java:95) ~[spring-context-5.1.4.RELEASE.jar:5.1.4.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.invokeBeanFactoryPostProcessors(AbstractApplicationContext.java:691) ~[spring-context-5.1.4.RELEASE.jar:5.1.4.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:528) ~[spring-context-5.1.4.RELEASE.jar:5.1.4.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:142) ~[spring-boot-2.1.2.RELEASE.jar:2.1.2.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:775) [spring-boot-2.1.2.RELEASE.jar:2.1.2.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:397) [spring-boot-2.1.2.RELEASE.jar:2.1.2.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:316) [spring-boot-2.1.2.RELEASE.jar:2.1.2.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1260) [spring-boot-2.1.2.RELEASE.jar:2.1.2.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1248) [spring-boot-2.1.2.RELEASE.jar:2.1.2.RELEASE]
at com.test.testservice.app.ApplicationKt.main(Application.kt:14) [classes/:na]
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_152]
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:1.8.0_152]
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:1.8.0_152]
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498) ~[na:1.8.0_152]
at org.springframework.boot.devtools.restart.RestartLauncher.run(RestartLauncher.java:49) [spring-boot-devtools-2.1.2.RELEASE.jar:2.1.2.RELEASE]
Caused by: java.io.FileNotFoundException: class path resource  [org/springframework/web/servlet/handler/HandlerInterceptorAdapter.class] cannot be opened because it does not exist
at org.springframework.core.io.ClassPathResource.getInputStream(ClassPathResource.java:180) ~[spring-core-5.1.4.RELEASE.jar:5.1.4.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.core.type.classreading.SimpleMetadataReader.<init>(SimpleMetadataReader.java:51) ~[spring-core-5.1.4.RELEASE.jar:5.1.4.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.core.type.classreading.SimpleMetadataReaderFactory.getMetadataReader(SimpleMetadataReaderFactory.java:103) ~[spring-core-5.1.4.RELEASE.jar:5.1.4.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.boot.type.classreading.ConcurrentReferenceCachingMetadataReaderFactory.createMetadataReader(ConcurrentReferenceCachingMetadataReaderFactory.java:88) ~[spring-boot-2.1.2.RELEASE.jar:2.1.2.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.boot.type.classreading.ConcurrentReferenceCachingMetadataReaderFactory.getMetadataReader(ConcurrentReferenceCachingMetadataReaderFactory.java:75) ~[spring-boot-2.1.2.RELEASE.jar:2.1.2.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.core.type.classreading.SimpleMetadataReaderFactory.getMetadataReader(SimpleMetadataReaderFactory.java:81) ~[spring-core-5.1.4.RELEASE.jar:5.1.4.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser.asSourceClass(ConfigurationClassParser.java:685) ~[spring-context-5.1.4.RELEASE.jar:5.1.4.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser$SourceClass.getSuperClass(ConfigurationClassParser.java:998) ~[spring-context-5.1.4.RELEASE.jar:5.1.4.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser.doProcessConfigurationClass(ConfigurationClassParser.java:332) ~[spring-context-5.1.4.RELEASE.jar:5.1.4.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser.processConfigurationClass(ConfigurationClassParser.java:242) ~[spring-context-5.1.4.RELEASE.jar:5.1.4.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser.processImports(ConfigurationClassParser.java:589) ~[spring-context-5.1.4.RELEASE.jar:5.1.4.RELEASE]
... 27 common frames omitted
```

Process finished with exit code 0

Dependencies look like this

```
[INFO] +- org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-starter-zipkin:jar:2.1.0.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-starter-sleuth:jar:2.1.0.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-sleuth-core:jar:2.1.0.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  |     +- org.aspectj:aspectjrt:jar:1.9.2:compile
[INFO] |  |     +- io.zipkin.brave:brave:jar:5.6.1:compile
[INFO] |  |     +- io.zipkin.brave:brave-context-log4j2:jar:5.6.1:compile
[INFO] |  |     +- io.zipkin.brave:brave-instrumentation-spring-web:jar:5.6.1:compile
[INFO] |  |     |  \- io.zipkin.brave:brave-instrumentation-http:jar:5.6.1:compile
[INFO] |  |     +- io.zipkin.brave:brave-instrumentation-spring-rabbit:jar:5.6.1:compile
[INFO] |  |     +- io.zipkin.brave:brave-instrumentation-kafka-clients:jar:5.6.1:compile
[INFO] |  |     +- io.zipkin.brave:brave-instrumentation-httpclient:jar:5.6.1:compile
[INFO] |  |     +- io.zipkin.brave:brave-instrumentation-httpasyncclient:jar:5.6.1:compile
[INFO] |  |     +- io.zipkin.brave:brave-instrumentation-spring-webmvc:jar:5.6.1:compile
[INFO] |  |     |  \- io.zipkin.brave:brave-instrumentation-servlet:jar:5.6.1:compile
[INFO] |  |     \- io.zipkin.brave:brave-instrumentation-jms:jar:5.6.1:compile
[INFO] |  \- org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-sleuth-zipkin:jar:2.1.0.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |     +- io.zipkin.zipkin2:zipkin:jar:2.12.0:compile
[INFO] |     +- io.zipkin.reporter2:zipkin-reporter:jar:2.7.14:compile
[INFO] |     +- io.zipkin.reporter2:zipkin-sender-kafka11:jar:2.7.14:compile
[INFO] |     \- io.zipkin.reporter2:zipkin-sender-amqp-client:jar:2.7.14:compile
```

I tried to go down to spring boot version 2.0.4, which is the next down available through maven, however then the Jersey package started bucking.

Is there a way to get zipkin and sleuth to work with spring boot 2.1.2?

Swagger seem to have a similar issue.

Comment: So to clarify the spring boot starter zipkin includes the sleuth dependency so try to remove the sleuth dependency.  See if you still get issues. Never mind I see your dependency tree. looks like the correct dependency.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Seems to work once I added the Web package. Though I don't recall it being needed previously.

Comment: If this answer doesnt solve issue:
I faced same issue with SB 2.6.7. In my case, culprit was wrong dependency already downloaded in .m2(may be previously). I cleaned up .m2 folder specifically for zipkin and sleuth, and rebuilding worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

I also faced the same problem. I downgraded the spring boot version from 2.6.3 to 2.5.9 then it worked.